# Indexing sections to plot in a MATLAB for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, indexing, plot

I have a matlab indexing question. I have a vector of 34 elements that I would like to plot in a for loop. However, I do not wish to plot them all at once. It would be great if I were able to plot elements 1:6, then 7:11, then 12:20, and so on. Is it possible to do this type of plotting in a for loop? If it is, I am having trouble with the indexing. Since these elements are all in sequential order, matlab seems to want to plot them all together. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
for i = 1: [1:6, 7:11, 12:20]  
    plot(x(i), y(i))  
end
```

Hopefully, I can get three plot, one with data from elements 1:6, another from elements 7:11, and the last one from elements 12:20.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Do you really need to plot these one point at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use a cell to store the variable-length vectors containing the various indices:

```
x = linspace(0, 1, 20);
y = x;
i_cell = {1:6, 7:11, 12:20};
for i = 1:length(i_cell)
    figure
    indices = i_cell{i}
    plot(x(indices), y(indices))
end
```

Comment: @bray_s Please do accept the answer if it works for you so that others who have a similar question know that this answer works.